# Is it OK to ask questions in other languages?

Tags: discussion, languages

The title is indeed a bit too general. I have seen that all stack exchange sites always use English as the language of their posts, save maybe in a few comments and in [one answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/10717/6273), which I translated from Chinese into English. There is, however, a notable exception: Italian SX. If you go there, and look at the [recent question list](https://italian.stackexchange.com/), you almost see more questions in Italian than in English. To make a few examples, [1](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3829/consumato-a-in-casa-oppure-consumato-a-a-casa), [2](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3827/qual-%C3%A8-luso-di-punto-in-questa-frase), [3](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/significato-e-uso-degli-accenti-diacritici-gravi-e-acuti-sulle-vocali-di-paro), [4](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/riflettere-su-versus-riflettere-a) and [5](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/significato-e-origine-dellespressione-allultima-spiaggia), and I know of at least one more. Interestingly, all but one (#3) of the above examples are by user [charo](https://italian.stackexchange.com/users/707/charo). Indeed, if you look at the questions on his user page, 1 out of the first 30 is in English, and the remaining 29 are all in Italian. Now, I know of the [proposal for Arabic SO](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75879/stackoverflow-in-arabic), which I anyway can't seem to find the result of (if there was one), and would anyway be a separate site specifically requiring Arabic posts, which Italian SX on the contrary doesn't. So I was wondering: is it appropriate to post in Italian on Italian SX? And more generally, is it appropriate to post in language X on X language SX? FOr example, in Chinese on Chinese SX? What should be done to users consistently posting in Italian on Italian SX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it is a site about a language, yes it is. It would be kind of silly to turn someone away because they posted their question in their own language on a site *about their own language*. That would be a pretty big slap in the face, and a pretty misleading site. "Come here to ask questions about the Italian language, *but don't you dare post in Italian*!"

Each language site has its own community and its own preferences. Some strongly prefer that users ask their questions and post their answers in the other language (kind of Rosetta Stone's full-immersion technique). Some even use that language for all of their tags. But Stack Exchange *is* still an English-based network, so English will still be an acceptable form of asking questions about each of these languages.

The only exception to this is sites that get created *in* another language. These sites are very different in that all of the wording, every single thing on the page, is in that other language. At this time, there are only two such sites:

- [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com)
- [Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)

These sites are "redos" of the existing Stack Overflow site explicitly created to cater to another language in its entirety. Asking a question in English on the Protuguese site would be completely off-topic, just like asking a question in Portuguese would be off-topic for the English site.